# How to copy all contents of folder if a folder contains a file with xyz string in ant?

Tags: build, ant

I have a folder directories of 3 javascript flies structured as given in image below
[image: folder structure]

each of these contains a separate js scripts and I have ant script like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="sample">
    <property file="build.properties"/>

    <target name="test">
        <copy todir="unlocked/">
            <fileset id="" dir="${par}">
                <include name="**/*.**"/>
                <contains text="extends Car"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
```

my Build.properties file contains

```
par = src/lwc
```

But this only copies the js file but not all contents of the file can you please help me out how to copy all the contents inside the folder if it contains certain text.
Ps: I am new to ant script.

Comment: are you defining the variable par by passing in value on the commandline or is it in build.properties?

Comment: @thekbb it is in build.properties

Comment: you should add it's value to your question